# Routeprovider injection

Tags: angularjs

What is the problem with the following code?

```
(function() {
  angular
  .module('myapp')
  .config(ConfigureProvider);

  ConfigureProvider.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

  function ConfigureProvider($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
      when('/',{                        
         templateUrl:'main.html', 
         controller:'GalleryController' 
      }).
      when('/1',{                   
         templateUrl:'favourites.html', 
         controller:'FavouritesController' 
      })
  }
})();
```

I am getting the following error:  `Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=myapp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined your module

```
angular.module('myapp',[])
```

and then

```
 angular
  .module('myapp')
  .config(ConfigureProvider);

  ConfigureProvider.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

  function ConfigureProvider($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
      when('/',{                        
         templateUrl:'main.html', 
         controller:'GalleryController' 
      }).
      when('/1',{                   
         templateUrl:'favourites.html', 
         controller:'FavouritesController' 
      })
  }
```